# Repeated Measure data.frame and ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Sorry if the question may be super silly for the majority but I literally just started this week to play around with R. 
I' m trying to build a data.frame with thresholds that have been collected several times (7 different time points) for each subject. 
That's how I organized my data so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

Subject <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
             "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",
             "3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3",
             "4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4")

Time <- rep(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), each = 7) 

Threshold <- c(-17, -24,    -27,    -40,    -25,    -23,    -37,    -40,
               -11, -12,    -11,    0,  -4, -7, -7, -4,
               -1,  -24,    -38,    -34,    -29,    -14,    -21,    -16,
               18,  -10,    -21,    -10,    -5, -17,    -3, -11)

Group <- c("Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active",            "Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active",           "Control","Control","Control","Control","Control","Control","Control","Control",
"sham","sham","sham","sham","sham","sham","sham","sham")
```

From my understanding this is how data must be arranged for repeated measure (in long format), but now the question: How can I select, for example, one column for one specific subject? Lets say I want to create a vector that contains the mean of the Threshold of all Subjects on Day 1.

And moreover, how can I plot lets say all the individual data with some `(Mean, Median)` superimposed to a `geom_point()` graph?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dplyr library to calculate a data frame of means, and then plot the points and the means.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Subject <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
             "2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",
             "3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3",
             "4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4")

Time <- rep(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), each = 4) 

Threshold <- c(-17, -24,    -27,    -40,    -25,    -23,    -37,    -40,
               -11, -12,    -11,    0,  -4, -7, -7, -4,
               -1,  -24,    -38,    -34,    -29,    -14,    -21,    -16,
               18,  -10,    -21,    -10,    -5, -17,    -3, -11)

Group <- c("Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active",
           "Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active","Active",
           "Control","Control","Control","Control","Control","Control","Control","Control",
           "sham","sham","sham","sham","sham","sham","sham","sham")

# data frame of raw data
df <- data.frame(Subject, Time, Threshold, Group)

# data frame of means
df_means <- group_by(df, Subject) %>% summarize(MeanThresh = mean(Threshold))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Subject, y = Threshold, color = Group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = df_means, aes(y = MeanThresh), size = 3, color = "black")
```

[image]

In general, dplyr will allow you to do whatever data filtering or other manipulations you may want to do, so I'd recommend to read up on it carefully.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. And if I can ask, how could I plot on the X axis the separate Days  and then every single subject as an separate point of the scatter plot? 
Thanks

Comment: We're working for reputation here. If an answer solves the problem or otherwise makes a valuable contribution, it is customary to upvote and possibly accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow too. Hope I did it right:)

Comment: It's up to you whether you want to upvote or click the checkmark or both. Upvote means: "This was constructive." Checkmark means: "This answered the question." Regarding your other question, this is basic ggplot2 aesthetic mapping. Please read [this chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#aesthetic-mappings) on aesthetic mapping and see if you can figure it out.